# Attempting to create a table using PhpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Does this look right the assignment was to create a table in MySql with the Fields:

Name - John
Address- 12 Main Street

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOphd.jpg

Comment: Yeah it is right but you can add an auto increment id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INSERT INTO josh101 (name, address) VALUES ('John', '12 Main Street');

This may help

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp